# Query results on every 6 months (display results 7 days before)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make an app for the "car maintenance shop".
In MySQL table I have

1. ID
2. CAR_PLATE
3. MAINTENANCE_DATE (timestamp)

Every car that goes to the maintenance, must come again after every 6 months for a new check.
When the car arrives for the first time, the date will be timestamped in field "maintenance_date".

**Question is...
How to display which car (license plate) is (let's say 7 days) near the period of the new check (maintenance)?**

*example*

**CAR_PLATE** = XYXYXY, 
 **MAINTENANCE_DATE** = 1.1.2018

At **25.6** I should get a car plate same as the date (d/m) of the new maintenance (exactly 6 months after) and it would be displayed until maintenance day passes.

P.S.

*I tried with "maintenance_date > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 7 DAY)";" but I am not on a good way..*

Comment: Hi @Peter, Can you show me the expected result. Maybe I can solve your problem.

Comment: What exactly do you need @VigneshVS ?

Comment: Do you need the CAR_PLATE details for the next maintenance?

Comment: Yes, to display what car plate have a next maintenance in next 7 days.

Comment: maintenance_date = CURDATE() - INTERVAL -1 DAY";  --> This is when interval is one day upfront, but not exactly 7 days before time expiration (6 months)

Comment: Okay. I have submitted my solution for this. You can check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will be helpful for you.

```
SELECT CAR_PLATE 
FROM table_name 
WHERE DATE_ADD(MAINTENANCE_DATE, INTERVAL 6 MONTH) 
BETWEEN CURDATE() AND (DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY));
```

If you are taking time for your comparison simply replace `NOW()` instead of `CURDATE()`.Check the code given below:

```
SELECT CAR_PLATE 
FROM table_name 
WHERE DATE_ADD(MAINTENANCE_DATE, INTERVAL 6 MONTH) 
BETWEEN NOW() AND (DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY));
```

I have attached my [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b7d78/7) with this. Thank you!

Comment: Hello Vignesh VS, you misunderstand me. 
Service check is on every 6 months, so If maintenance_date is 01.01.2018 next one is 01.07.2018, so 7 days before 01.07 I need to display results from query :)

Comment: @Peter I have updated my solution. You can check it. I hope this is actually you want.

Comment: Wow, thank you, champion! It works! :))
I have one additional question, can I add something like "DATE_ADD(MAINTENANCE_DATE, INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AS nextcheck" so I can display out exactly date that is 6 months after "|maintenance_date"?

Comment: Hi Peter, If it work for you accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: Good luck  @Peter

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, simple approach to select records where the difference in days is between 0 and 7 (in the future).

```
SELECT ID, CAR_PLATE, MAINTENANCE_DATE
  FROM <Table>
 WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, NOW(), MAINTENANCE_DATE) BETWEEN 0 AND 7
;
```